# Select List of another List by separating delimiter in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, delimiter

I'm trying to select a list which is having another list itself. But the thing is I've needed to use some delimiter to separate my two list

My List is

```
{
    "Order": {
        "Items": [
            {
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "Product": "XXX",
                        "Category": "YYY"
                    },
                    {
                        "Product": "ZZZ",
                        "Category": "YYY"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "Product": "AAA",
                        "Category": "BBB"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My Final output should be like

```
XXX|YYYY^ZZZ|YYY^AAA|BBB
```

Currently, I'm using the solution as like below.

```
 StringBuilder output= new StringBuilder();
 string delimiter = "";
 foreach (var items in order.Items) {
      output.Append(delimiter);
      output.Append(string.Join("^",items.Details.Select(l => l.Product+"|"+l.Category)));
      delimiter = "^";
 }
```

But this is not the best option. Please help to find the good one.

Comment: Why isn't this the correct approach?

Comment: @AlexRiabov I've updated the question. I'm trying to get a single command using the LINQ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a single `string.Join` with LINQ's [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany):

```
string result = string.Join("^", order.Items.SelectMany(
          item => item.Details.Select(detail => $"{detail.Product}|{detail.Category}")));
```

This goes through all `Details` of all `Items` and creates your "Product|Category" strings. Then these strings are all joined with "^" as delimiter.

---

I don't know your criteria for "good". If you find this readable and think your co-workers will also understand it, I guess it's good. There maybe more efficient ways (in terms of consumed time), but I think this will only be a real matter if you have billions of `Details` or need to execute it twice per millisecond.

Comment: @Rene Vogt Yes, I was referring to the more readable. You are mentioning more efficient ways (consumed time). Can you guide what are those? As of now, my understanding is using **LINQ** will be good performance over *for/foreach* loop for iterating any List

Comment: @Jayendran no that's really wrong: Linq really is only a more concise way to write `foreach` loops. It does exactly the same like a `foreach`. What could be improved here (made faster) is the way the strings are build. A little bit faster way would be two nested `foreach` loops (items and details) filling a `StringBuilder`. The concatenation of the inner strings is what makes my code "slow". But keep in mind that the difference is very very small. So if you don't like verbose code, there is no need to do this, your users will never feel the difference of 5ms vs 7ms.

Comment: @Jayendran There's a nice blog by Jon Skeet: [edulinq](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/) where he re-invents LINQ. If you want to understand how linq works, it's worth a read.